# IV in RSA Encrypted Private Key

Tags: rsa, aes, public-key, initialization-vector

I have been provided an RSA encrypted private key which was generated in NodeJS (crypto) using the following:

```
generateKeyPairSync( "rsa", {
        modulusLength: 4096,
        publicKeyEncoding: {
          type: "spki",
          format: "pem"
        },
        privateKeyEncoding: {
          type: "pkcs8",
          format: "pem",
          cipher: "aes-256-cbc",
          passphrase: "aWCTJPET9fL7UBTp97hX99gdofeWKUf5tuxSuJeST2sEkyvkyinrfrj6EiSUTErF"
        }
      } )

Note: enforcing padding in encrypt and decrypt padding: RSA_PKCS1_PADDING
```

My task is to get the PRIVATE KEY  by decrypting the ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY.
I have the password as shown above and the other particulars. Everything but the IV.

This will have to be done manually as I have to use Java and it has a few issues:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13  (Password-Based Encryption Scheme 2 (PBES2))
```

Unfortunately, the library used within NodeJS (crypto) to generate the ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY does not supply the IV which is required in combination with the passphrase to decrypt the AES-256 CBC encrypted PRIVATE KEY.

I am reading that the IV can be acquired from the key and this is how the NodeJS library is able to decrypt the file while only asking for the passphrase from the user.

I would like to know how I can derive the IV from the ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY.

An IV in AES is always the size of the block, which in AES's case is 128-bits, or 16 bytes. So the way I am looking at it is which 16 bytes are the IV in the encrypted private key. It would also be nice to know how from a 16byte [] to reconstruct the bytes to get the IV.

I attach all forms of the key--encrypted, decrypted and the associated public key--as you may need it for testing.

ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

DECRYPTED PRIVATE KEY

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

PUBLIC KEY

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: Actually this OP doesn't need it, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286457/load-an-encrypted-pcks8-pem-private-key-in-java -- but someone else in a different situation (not Java) might

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run

> openssl asn1parse -in keyfileName

You'll see a bunch of output, I believe the field after "aes-256-cbc" is the IV

> ```
>  0:d=0  hl=4 l=2477 cons: SEQUENCE
>  4:d=1  hl=2 l=  87 cons: SEQUENCE
>  6:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :PBES2
> 17:d=2  hl=2 l=  74 cons: SEQUENCE
> 19:d=3  hl=2 l=  41 cons: SEQUENCE
> 21:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :PBKDF2
> 32:d=4  hl=2 l=  28 cons: SEQUENCE
> 34:d=5  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:459A7208041047CA
> 44:d=5  hl=2 l=   2 prim: INTEGER           :0800
> 48:d=5  hl=2 l=  12 cons: SEQUENCE
> 50:d=6  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OBJECT            :hmacWithSHA256
> 60:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
> 62:d=3  hl=2 l=  29 cons: SEQUENCE
> 64:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :aes-256-cbc
> 75:d=4  hl=2 l=  16 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEXDUMP]:BC87885E3BC691E4D689AB9A3CF66C81
> ```

I believe the 0800 (i.e. 1024) is the number of iterations of PBKDF2 that's used.

Comment: It is; and the value just before 0800 is the salt. Adding `-i` (lower eye) to `asn1parse` makes the structure clearer.

Comment: This might help others as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286457/load-an-encrypted-pcks8-pem-private-key-in-java/66291601#66291601